At what point is a base class member considered to be hidden?
Clang rejects the following program:
struct g { static constexpr bool b = true; };
struct h : g { static constexpr bool b = b; }; // clang nope, gcc ok, msvc ok
static_assert(h::b);

My take on this is that Clang tries to initialize variable b by itself. But, since variable b is still uninitialized, reading from it leads to undefined behavior, which is not allowed in a constant expression.
However, GCC and MSVC both accept this program. Suggesting that they simply resolve h::b's initialization value from its base member g::b. Which begs the questions: At what point does h::b starts to hide its base member g::b?
Of course, qualifying b could solve this discrepancy altogether, but that is besides the point of this question.
Demo

Clang's error message:
<source>:2:38: error: constexpr variable 'b' must be initialized by a
constant expression
    2 | struct h : g { static constexpr bool b = b; };
      |                                      ^   ~
<source>:2:42: note: read of object outside its lifetime is not allowed in a
constant expression
    2 | struct h : g { static constexpr bool b = b; };
      |                                          ^


If you change it to static constexpr bool b = h::b;, GCC and MSVC both still accept the program. I dunno if that's significant.

"Of course, qualifying b could solve this discrepancy altogether, but that is besides the point of this question." depends on what you expect, i think b is h::b and then gcc still compiles without complaints while clang not https://godbolt.org/z/9nWMhnr6b

@463035818_is_not_an_ai: But gcc actually uses the value from g::b.  https://godbolt.org/z/7sax1W6qe  Even when you write it as h::b https://godbolt.org/z/adGrhGbTv

@NateEldredge oh my. Weird case. And I am not the only one who got confused :D

And if you remove the : g, making it struct h { static constexpr bool b = h::b; };, GCC and MSVC both say there's no such thing as h::b, while Clang says you can't read h::b outside of its lifetime in a constant expression. So I don't think the base class is really important for displaying the discrepancy. It looks like the real issue is the visibility of the declaration in h, regardless of whether it hides a declaration in g.

It seems like to gcc and msvc, the new object b is not in scope within its own initializer (and so b is resolved to the existing class member), whereas for clang it is (but can't successfully be read).

And yet in a simpler context without constexpr, with int x = x; the x on the right side is the new (uninitialized) object, not the object of the same name from an enclosing scope.  https://godbolt.org/z/YMdxrn774

But, since variable b is still uninitialized...  Since b is a static variable, it is initialized.

@user2357112: To make the GCC and MSVC behavior even more confusing, compare struct h { static constexpr bool b = (sizeof h::b); };


Suggesting that they simply resolve h::b's initialization value from its base member g::b. Which begs the questions: At what point does h::b starts to hide its base member g::b?

The locus of the declaration is immediately after the declarator, i.e. here after the b token, before the = token. (see [basic.scope.pdecl]/1)
From that point lookup will be able to find the declared name and so it will hide the base class b. (see [basic.lookup.general]/2 and following)
The second b in static constexpr bool b = b; refers to the member being defined, not to the one in the base class.
The question is whether or not the initialization is well-formed.
First suppose it was not marked constexpr. Then (assuming the proposed resolution of CWG 2821), the initialization would be well-formed and would have well-defined behavior:
b is a static storage duration variable that has zero initialization followed by dynamic initialization. After the zero initialization b's lifetime has begun (under the proposed resolution of CWG 2821). Then reading b during the dynamic initialization would be allowed. b would have value false at this point and initialize b with false again.
Adding constexpr complicates the matter a bit. Now, the initialization must be a constant expression, which would imply that it can't have dynamic initialization, so that the above observation of the zero-initialized state is impossible.
Because the trick with zero-initialization can't work in that case, it can't really work out without undefined behavior. Unfortunately I think that the rules for determining whether the variable's initialization is a constant expression are currently circular for this case and can't give an answer.
Maybe CWG 2186 is relevant: Depending on what "preceding initialization" in [expr.const] means, it may not apply to b when it is used in the initializer. Then the expression can't be a constant expression because the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on b is not allowed in a constant expression at that point.

CWG2536 is about whether constant initialization of objects with static and thread storage duration should observe a prior zero-initialization if it reads from the object before writing.

"From that point lookup will be able to find the declared name and so it will hide the base class b." A reference to the applicable standerdese that outlines these rules/steps in more detail would be highly appreciated.

"Unfortunately I think that the rules for determining whether the variable's initialization is a constant expression are currently circular for this case and can't give an answer." So, does this fall into the category of IFNDR? Or, is this rather some unnamed category of its own?

@303 Assuming that the definition is really circular, that would fall in the category "the standard isn't sound". That would be a defect in the specification. I am not sure that I am fully correct on that though.

@BrianBi Hm, the possible solution suggested in the issue doesn't really seem to clear it up for me. To determine whether or not b's definition is well-formed I need to determine whether the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on b is permitted as a core constant expression. First, it is not completely clear to me whether or not the lifetime of b starts during the constant expression evaluation (and how that is affected by possible prior zero-initialization). If the lifetime starts during the expression, then there is a question of whether this happens before or after the conversion.

If the lifetime does not start during the expression, then it is not clear to me whether or not b is usable in constant expressions, because it may be if it is constant-initialized and "preceding initialization" does include the situation (which is where I see the possible circularity). If it is, then I am not sure how the value of the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is supposed to be determined either. The initialization doesn't leave b uninitialized, so the suggested resolution wouldn't apply. So the zero-initialization necessary to start the lifetime wouldn't exist. It would be UB(?).

All in all, I think this is really confusing at the moment.

@303 Btw., see references in my edit to the answer.
